# euro symbol changed after update asp.net nopcommerce

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, localization, nopcommerce

I did some modifications on the code for a nopcommerce project and after I published the changes the euro sign was changed to some other sign not understandable for us. What can be the reason for that since no changes occured in that part of the website.

Please take a look at this page for reference:

Example image: http://gyazo.com/9b57d307ba597b9ed689889f5ee4bc85.png?1343658375

So instead of 'Ђ' character there should be '€'

Thanks, Angel

Comment: The problem occurs because the euro symbol is character 128 in Windows code page 1252 (Latin, West Europe); the letter 'Ђ' is character 128 in code page 1251 (Cyrillic).  At some point, it seems, the character is being converted from 8-bit encoding, using the wrong code page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using symbols try the html entities. In this case `&euro;` which is the € sign. For more entities see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Comment: Using entities in HTML is largely a hack and a workaround for when encoding is unreliable. Ideally the only entities you need are `&quot;`, `&gt;`, `&lt;` and `&amp;`, everything else should be preserved by encoding. I suggest the OP should ensure that the correct encoding is used throughout the application.